# Error connecting to ODBC data source from JDBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

There is no error while compiling, but I'm getting this error on running my program:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Here is my code for inserting values in table in SQL Server.

```
import javax. swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import java.sql.*;

        class login  implements ActionListener

        {
        JFrame loginframe;
        JPanel loginpanel, loginpanel1;
        JLabel name, password, loginhead, loginstatus;
        JTextField nametxt;
        JPasswordField passwordtxt;
        JButton loginsubmit, loginreset;

        public login()
        {
        loginframe=new JFrame();
        loginframe.setSize(300,300);
        loginframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(loginframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loginframe.setVisible(true);

        loginpanel=new JPanel();
        loginpanel1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2));

        loginhead=new JLabel("Login");
        loginstatus=new JLabel("");
        name=new JLabel("Name");
        password=new JLabel("Password");

        nametxt=new JTextField(10);
        passwordtxt=new JPasswordField(10);


        loginsubmit=new JButton("submit");
        loginsubmit.addActionListener(this);
        loginreset=new JButton("Reset");
        loginreset.addActionListener(this);



        loginpanel1.add(loginhead);
        loginpanel1.add(loginstatus);
        loginpanel1.add(name);
        loginpanel1.add(nametxt);
        loginpanel1.add(password);
        loginpanel1.add(passwordtxt);
        loginpanel1.add(loginsubmit);
        loginpanel1.add(loginreset);


        loginpanel.add(loginpanel1);

        loginframe.add(loginpanel);

        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
        String name=nametxt.getText();
        String pass=passwordtxt.getText();
        if(ae.getSource()==loginsubmit)
        {
        String url1="jdbc:odbc:"+"login";
        try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(url1);
        Statement s=c.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement ps=c.prepareStatement("insert into signup values(?,?)");
        s.executeUpdate("create table signup(First_name varchar(20), Password varchar(20))");
        System.out.println("Basic information table created");
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,pass);
        ps.execute();
        System.out.println("Values inserted");
        s.close();
        c.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
        }


        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        login l=new login();
        }
        }
```

Comment: You need relavant jdbc jar file to connect database.

Comment: can you please be more specific.i am new to JDBC.

Comment: There are connectors those are jar files using to connect database. For my SQL it is MySQL connector.

Comment: do you use netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? The JDBC-ODBC bridge was removed in Java 8.

Comment: thanks.iam using java 8 i guess tats d reason it aint working

Comment: @Guneli currently i do on notepad.

Comment: @Mureinik will it work in java 7 ??

Comment: @Allan probably, but the easiest way to find out is to try it.

Comment: Don't use the ODBC bridge - not even on versions prior to Java8. It's buggy and slow. Use a native JDBC driver instead.

Comment: @Mureinik ya will do that.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8. In order to connect to the SQL Server database you will need to use a real JDBC driver. The one offered by Microsoft is:

[Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when i had to connect my java code to MSAccess.
yes The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is removed from Java 8 and later versions. Now if you want to connect java code to database either use jdk7 you can get it  [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html)

register and login here for downloading jdk 7.

connect database with traditional method by going through Control Panel-Administrative tool-ODBC etc.

Comment: If you have jdk 7 it is actually possible to copy the jdbc.odbc-bridge over to jdk 8. (https://support.migration-center.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012716534-How-to-enable-JDBC-ODBC-bridge-for-Java-8-)